# Restoring telerik's nuget package during Jenkins build

Tags: telerik, nuget, kendo-asp.net-mvc, nuget-package-restore

On my development machine i have successfully configured visual studio for telerik's package source. Based on our current license it shows the latest `Telerik.UI.for.AspNet.Core` package we can download is version `2016.3.1118` *(along with other old versions)*
So on development machine i installed the version `2016.3.1118` and tested successfully.

Now, i am trying to publish the solution on our Jenkins build server. Jenkins executes the following command to restore packages and publish

```
dotnet publish wmp.sln -c Release
```

However, Im getting error on the build server

> error NU1102: Unable to find package Telerik.UI.for.AspNet.Core with
>   version (>= 2016.3.1118) [D:\Jenkins\wmp\workspace\wmp.sln]
>   error NU1102:   - Found 1 version(s) in nuget.org [ Nearest version:
>   2016.3.914 ] [D:\Jenkins\cr-wmp\workspace\wmp.sln]

**UPDATE 1**

I use the [instructions](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/installation/installing-the-telerik-controls-from-nuget-package) to setup Telerik's Nuget Package Feed

*(Note that i do have another ASP.NET Core project that is using version `2016.3.914`. This project also configured with another Jenkins Job for CI. and it has no issue restoring and publishing)*

Answer (score 1):

Your error says

> error NU1102: - Found 1 version(s) in nuget.org

which means it's not checking Telerik's package source. You didn't explain exactly how you added the source, but given the message quoted above, and you said you "configured visual studio", I assume you used the NuGet->Package Sources UI in Visual Studio's Tools->Options. Unfortunately NuGet's options dialog only supports user profile settings, not NuGet's hierarchical settings capability. Therefore using the VS UI to add the source makes it available for every solution on your user account on that computer, but not other accounts on the same computer, or when that solution is used on another computer.

You should create a [nuget.config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file) in your repository and use the [packageSources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#package-source-sections) to specify your package sources. If you have the .NET Core SDK installed on your machine, you can use `dotnet new nugetconfig` to create the file from a template. Once you have a nuget.config with your package sources configured checked into your source code repository, when it's checked out on the CI agent, NuGet will know to check Telerik's feed on restore.

Comment: Thanks. What if i don't want to configure Telerik's package feed on the build server, can i just copy the package from my local machine to build server into `C:\Users\{username}\.nuget\packages\Telerik.UI.for.AspNet.Core\` folder? (i tried this but it didn't work. May be i need to do some extra settings??)

Comment: @LP13 Hi, were you able to resolve the issue? If so, how?